# Pattern Match Failure in List in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I have one problem with pattern matching. When I give input to **(x:y:ys)**  the list containing 3 elements, hugs complain that there is: **pattern match failure**.
I guess that the problem is here

```
takeNearestOnes agent (y:ys) (x:nearestOnes)
```

because it fails to match three elements with list containing two elements

This is full code:

```
takeNearestOnes agent (x:y:ys) nearestOnes
            | first == second =  takeNearestOnes agent (y:ys) (x:nearestOnes)
            | otherwise = (x:nearestOnes)
        where first=(manhattanDistance x (agentCoord agent))
              second=(manhattanDistance y (agentCoord agent)
```

How can I overcome this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function is recursive and decreasing the list, you could eventually going to work you're way down to a list of 1 element, in which case your match will fail. You can fix this by adding another case of your function which handles it however you feel is appropriate

Something like

```
takeNearestOnes agent [x] nearestOnes = doSomething
takeNearestOnes agent []  nearestOnes = doSomethingElse
```

Comment: I see what I must do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What should be the result of `takeNearestOnes agent [x] nearestOnes`? What should be the result of `takeNearestOnes agent [] nearestOnes`?

Write extra equations for these cases.